# JavaFX printing non node objects

Tags: printing, javafx-8, pdfrenderer

I want to print a [PDFFile](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.swinglabs/pdf-renderer/1.0.5/com/sun/pdfview/PDFFile.java) object from the [Pdf-Renderer](https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer) library using javafx printing. Is it possible to print non [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) objects? Currently i'm using AWT printing ([check this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html)) but it doesn't go well with javafx because my javafx window freezes when the AWT print dialog comes up.

```
Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
if (job != null) {
    boolean success = job.printPage(node); // use something otherthan a node(PDFFile in my case)
    if (success) {
        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a `java.awt.Image` from each page, draw the page to a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` convert the `BufferedImage` to a `javafx.scene.image.Image`, and finally print an `ImageView` containing the image:

Something like:

```java
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
PDFFile pdfFile = ... ;
if (job != null) {
    boolean success = true ;
    for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= pdfFile.getNumPages() ; pageNumber++) {
        PDFPage page = pdfFile.getPage(pageNumber, true);
        Rectangle2D bounds = page.getBBox();
        int width = (int) bounds.getWidth();
        int height = (int) bounds.getHeight();
        java.awt.Image img = page.getImage(width, height, bounds, null, true, true);
        BufferedImage bImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        bImg.createGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        javafx.scene.image.Image fxImg = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bImg, null);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(fxImg);
        success = success & job.printPage(imageView);
    }

    if (success) {
        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

Note that this code can be executed off the FX Application Thread, to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: thanks for the answer @james_d. will i lose clarity when i zoom in on the output? (ie raster or vector)